# AngularJS form validation : $dirty value change through ui.router state changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-form

**My use case :**

I have a multi step form using ui-router like in the plunkr below. I use ng-form to validate information provided by AngularJS, like $valid, $dirty etc.

After each click on the "Next section" button, I send the form data to the server in order to retrieve it, in case the user quits the form before finishing.

If the user submits the first step twice, I ONLY send the edited data (if the $dirty value is true). All of this is not in the plunkr, I chose to show you a simple form, but my form can contain a hundred fields (radio, checkbox, input, select etc.).

**The steps to reproduce the issue (plunkr) :**

1. Fill step 1 and go to next section
2. Check xbox radio and return to step 1 by clicking on the number 
   `myMultiStepForm.interests.xbox.$dirty = true`
3. Come back to step 2 
   **`myMultiStepForm.interests.xbox.$dirty = false`**

Why is $dirty value changed to false? I guess it's because the `<ng-form>` is displayed again and all validation data is reset.

Is there a way to avoid this ? Or maybe something other than `<ng-form>` to handle validation of subsets of fields ?

This is the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/WclqVgiBvUXlsGdSCcj0?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you link a form or any controller inside it, it always starts out as `$pristine`. The reason is that the models like `formData.type` simply have some values, angular has no way to know that those values were the default state, coming from the server, or are the result of previous user interaction; they are a simple `string` or something without this kind of metadata attached.

To achieve what you want, you have to manually track the `$dirty` state across state transitions, and apply `$setDirty` on the form when needed.

Here is a quick example, adding a controller to the form step pages, which saves the form state on exit (to a shared service instance, you could add this via `resolve` too) and restores it at construction. The current `formPage` is injected via a default parameter value so that the same controller can be used for all steps.

```js
// router:

$stateProvider.state('form.interests', {
  url: '/interests',
  controller: 'FormStepController',  
  params: { formPage: 'interests'}
  templateUrl: 'form-interests.html'
})

// state

angular.value("formDirtyState", {});

// controller

angular.controller("FormStepController", function($scope, formDirtyState, $stateParams) {
  var formPage = stateParams.formPage;

  for(var formField in $scope.myMultiStepForm[formPage]) {
    if(formDirtyState[formPage] && formDirtyState[formPage][formField])
      $scope.myMultiStepForm[formPage][formField].$setDirty()
  }
    

  $scope.$on("$destroy", function() { 
    for(var formField in $scope.myMultiStepForm[formPage])
      formDirtyState[formField] = $scope.myMultiStepForm[formPage][formField].$dirty;
  })

})
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this... I think the $destroy trick can fix the issue. I try to implement this on my app and will let you know thank you

Answer (score 2):

I solved and the solution is in the below plunker.

**Referring to this :**

> Note: the purpose of ngForm is to group controls, but not to be a
>   replacement for the  tag with all of its capabilities (e.g.
>   posting to the server, ...).

as per [**Angular Documentation for ngForm element**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm).

Also I wonder why you are using many `<ng-form>` elements. 
This is the only possible solution for your problem.

[`Plunker Modified`](http://plnkr.co/edit/IiaW6Lun2K5bOfjp6kWa?p=preview)

Update 1:

### **Explanation for $dirty**

**$dirty** is set to true only if the **user interacted** with that particular element in the current scope.

If you're so particular with true/false problem

- Suggesting you to replace the **$dirty** to **$pristine**

Update 2 :

### Why is the value not true when navigating again back

When you navigate from one form to another the **scope** of the ng-form of that particular element is added to the parent controller, when the same ng-form is visited again it **overrides** with that of the existing one.

Comment: Can you please explain your changes ? By following the same scenario in my question, I've got `myMultiStepForm.interests.$dirty = false` at the end. Also I used many <ng-form> to know each field validation and not the global form validation. How would you do without all these <ng-form> ?

Comment: You can use multiple ng-form tags to combine controls that may not be located in the same DOM hierarchy.  A classic example of this is a submit input on a modal where the button resides in a modal's footer.

Comment: yes. it can be used in the case of combining controls. but in this case I think it is not necessary to have <ng-form> for every control of the form element. Correct me if am wrong!!

Comment: I think you don't understand, my initial issue is : I don't know why the $dirty value doesn't stay true when the user interact with the input and navigate thought the multi step form. The answer's plunkr doesn't solve this issue

Comment: I clearly understood your question. the problem is when you navigate from one form to another the **scope** of the ng-form of that particular element  is added to the parent controller, when the same ng-form is visited again it **overrides** with that of the existing one.

Comment: Ok that's the explanation I was waiting for :) So using ng-form that way is not going to help me solve my issue. Maybe I should not use the $dirty value, but I don't see a simple way without compare the input values from the server each time

Comment: Yes. Any other explanation u need?

Comment: No, your explanation is fine now thank you. I just need another approach to solve the issue